# Set docx file to HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-poi, httpresponse, docx

I am trying to set a **docx** file a response to an api to be downloaded as an **attachment**. But when I download the file generated by the API, it is **corrupted** and can not be opened, even if the initial file is fine and can be displayed.
This is my controller method:

```
        byte[] fileAsBytes= readFileToByteArray(new File(fileLocation))
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "output.docx");
        response.getOutputStream().write(fileAsBytes);
```

The method used to get the byte array

```
public static byte[] readFileToByteArray(File file){
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        byte[] bArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            fis.read(bArray);
            fis.close();
        }catch(IOException ioExp){
            ioExp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bArray;
    }
```

When i try to open the downloaded file it says "Word found unreadable content" and "Word experienced an error when trying to open the file"

The method in the controller class:

```
    @ApiOperation("get file as bytes")
    @PostMapping("/get-file")
    public void getFileAsbytes(HttpServletRequest request,
                                     HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        byte[] fileAsBytes= documentsService.getFileAsBytes();

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "output.docx");
        response.getOutputStream().write(fileAsBytes);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

Comment: Is the response object HttpServletRespone? Try this: `response.flushBuffer();` after writing to the stream.

Comment: I tested your code and is working fine. How are you consuming this API?

Comment: @JakubBiernaczyk yes, the object is HttpServletResponse. I tried to add flushBuffer() after response.getOutputStream().write(fileAsBytes) but still getting the same problem.

Comment: @delephin I updated the code with the controller method and i consume it via Swagger

Comment: Apparently the problem is with swagger when in packs the file up. I tried to make a GET from POST with hardcoded values and call it in the browser and the file is downloaded and it is fine.

Comment: I've also tested with postman GET/POST and it worked perfectly, so I agree the issue must be with swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with swagger2 version. This bug is fixed in version 3.0.0